# How can I check DNS using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dns

I need to do recursive check DNS, like linux's command

```
$ dig +recurse some.site
```

with nodejs. This 'request' have to return object of DNS, because I need to work with them.

I need this feature to take rightly DNS, it have to get round TTL(I'm not sure that it correctly sounds on English). Can standard dns module  do this?

Comment: Please check if  https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done it!
I used [this module](https://github.com/tjfontaine/node-dns).

First I define question:

```
var question = dns.Question({
  name: 'somesite.com',
  type: 'A',
});
```

Second I do request to root server:

```
var dns = require('native-dns');
var standard_dns = require('dns'); //for dns.lookup() function    
var req = dns.Request({
      question: question,
      server: { address: '199.7.91.13', port: 53, type: 'udp' },
      timeout: 1000,
    });
```

Then I do this:

```
req.on('message', function (err, answer) {
  answer.authority.forEach(function(a){ //looking each authority server
    var addresses = String(a.data),//stringify it
    standard_dns.lookup(addresses, function(e, add){ //lookup this server with standard 'dns' module
      var req = dns.Request({
         question: question,//question for somesite.com
         server: {address: add}//do request on this server
      })
      req.on('message', function(e, a){
        console.log(a);//a - is what you need
       })
     req.send(); //send request
    })

  })
});
```

Comment: That's good you got it working. Since I directed you to that module is my answer worth an upvote?

Answer (score 12):

You could use [the core DNS module](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html). The first example they give does a lookup of `www.google.com`

```
var dns = require('dns');

dns.lookup('www.google.com', function onLookup(err, addresses, family) {
  console.log('addresses:', addresses);
});
```

Also have a look at this [native-dns](https://github.com/tjfontaine/node-dns) module

Comment: I need this feature to take rightly DNS, it have to get round TTL(I'm not sure that it correctly sounds on English). Standard dns module can do this?

Comment: Any advice if the DNS module can't find `www.google.com` even if your browser on the same computer can?